# Elasticsearch: How can I get an count of documents by the number of items within a property?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have an Elasticsearch documents that look like this

```
{
    "_index": "sample.index",
    "_type": "inventory",
    "_id": "ebcc7f5c-1697-438f-911f-b8e9ff5554e9",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "name": "salt",
        "properties": {
            "vendors": ["vendor 1", "vendor 2"]
        }
    }
},
{
    "_index": "sample.index",
    "_type": "inventory",
    "_id": "f5875c5c-9bf1-448b-99d9-47d873d4f016",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "name": "pepper",
        "properties": {
            "vendors": ["vendor 1"]
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is get the count of items that can come from one vendor, two vendors, etc... Basically, a query based on the length of the vendors array.

This is the type of output I'm trying to obtain, or something similar.

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "vendor_counts": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "vendor_array_length": "1",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "vendor_array_length": "2",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

EDIT: The below accepted answer appears to work for newer versions of ES, but I'm having to use an older version (I found that out after originally posting this question). The following query works for me on ES 2.4.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "length": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "_source.vendors.size()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "length": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "params._source.vendors.length",
          "lang": "painless"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me because I found out that the version of ES I'm having to work with is older. However, it appears your query works for newer versions. You did inspire me and I managed to put together another query. I'll post it below. Thanks!!!

Comment: If you tell me which version you have, I can provide a query that works with your version

Comment: Sorry, it's version 2.4. I added that to the original question too.

Comment: Ok, glad you figured it out.